# Javascript code Object Expected Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error at run time can any body help me out why i am getting this Error?

Thanks

```
ShowHelpTopic('/Help/Help2.htm');;void(0)
```

This is the Error I am getting in the Dynamic mode page.

This is my code in the page.

```
stm_aix("p3i0", "p1i0", [0, "Searching for items in Benefit Code list", "", "", -1, -1, 0, "javascript:ShowHelpTopic('/Help/Help1.htm')", "_self", "", "Help Topics", "060508icon4.gif", "060508icon5.gif"], 526, 0);stm_aix("p3i0", "p1i0", [0, "Creating new Benefit Codes", "", "", -1, -1, 0, "javascript:ShowHelpTopic('/Help/Help2.htm')", "_self", "", "Help Topics", "060508icon4.gif", "060508icon5.gif"], 526, 0);
```

This `ShowHelpTopic` function in my js file.

```
function ShowHelpTopic(url){
    window.open(url, "HelpTopics", "height=600,width=900,resizable=1,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,scrollbars=1,status=0");
}
```

Why am I getting a run time error in my asp.net mvc application?

Comment: I'd guess your `item` variable isn't an object, how do you initialise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `urls` doesn't exist when you are prepending it to itself or `item` is null. Because this sample is fine:

```
var urls = "", 
    item = {helpLinkDescription: 'a', helpLink1: 'google'};
urls += 'stm_aix("p3i0", "p1i0", [0, "' + item.helpLinkDescription + "\", \"\", \"\", -1, -1, 0, \"" + "javascript:ShowHelpTopic('" + item.helpLink1 + "');" + "\", \"_self\", \"\", \"Help Topics\", \"060508icon4.gif\", \"060508icon5.gif\"], 526, 0);";
```